# How does Delphi calculate TDateTime as a Float value?

Tags: delphi, tdatetime

I am new in `Delphi` programming.
While going through the `Data Types` in `Delphi` I found `TDateTime`.

While using it in my test application I come to know that the `TDateTime` Object provide me a `Float\Double` value.

I am little curious about `TDateTime` How it calculate the `Date Time` to `Double` value.

Below is the example code which I had used:

```
var
  LDateTime: TDateTime;
  LFloat: Double;
begin
   LDateTime := now;// current DateTime
   LFloat:= LDateTime; // provide me a float value   
end;
```

Is it using any formula to calculate `Date and Time Value` from Windows?

Can anyone suggest/provide me for some more information about working of `TDateTime`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you tried reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TDateTime)?

Comment: Just for the record, `TDateTime` is not an object; it is a typedef of `type double`. From *System.pas*:  `type  TDateTime = type Double;`. There's no need to use `LFloat` to do any sort of conversion; you can directly use a `TDateTime` as a floating point value, as in `MyDate := Now + 10;` (add 10 days).

Answer (score 14):

The float represents the number of days since 30.12.1899. So float value = 1 would be 31.12.1899, 2 = 01.01.1900 and so on. The time is saved as a fraction of the day. 0.25 = 06:00, 0.5 = 12:00, 0.75 = 18.00 ...

So the 31.12.1899 12:00 would be equal to 1.5.

This makes TDateTime really easy to work with. To get the difference in days just substract two DateTimes.

02.01.2015 - 01.01.2015 = 1

Simple as it can be. To get the difference in hours just multiply by 24.

Also have a look at the functions in Unit DateUtils. They come in handy at times.

Comment: Also, the formula itself can be found under `EncodeDate` in unit SysUtils

Comment: Note that using TDateTime as a Double is an implementation detail and should be avoided. There are lots of routines that handles TDateTime values is SysUtils and DateUtils. See [Date and Time Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Date_and_Time_Support).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
function DateTimeToUnix(const AValue: TDateTime): Int64;
```

and

```
function UnixToDateTime(const AValue: Int64): TDateTime;
```

functions from `DateUtils.pas`

`TDateTime` value can be formatted by `FormatDateTime` function

```
//uses sysutils

var    
  k:double;    
  t:tdatetime    
begin    
  t:=UnixToDateTime(1483909200);    
  showmessage(datetostr(t));    
  t:=strtodate('08.01.2017');    
  k:=DateTimeToUnix(t);    
  showmessage(k.ToString);    
end;
```